# Access a property of a css block from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, constants

I have a site that is heavily based on javascript, but I still want to let it be easily modified by CSS.
Take this example... there is a div that it has its opacity modified when on hover through jQuery, but I would like to the designer to be able to choose the value of the opacity.
I was thinking on creating a block in css just to declare this constants, for example:

```
.constants_someid{
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

and then through jQuery I take this opacity like

```
 var opacity = jQuery('css:constants_someid').attr('opacity');
```

I don't know if this is a good way to do these constants declaration, but thats what came to mind right now.

What you guys think?

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define them in a Javascript file instead:

```
var settings = {
    opacity: 0.5
};
```

That kind of syntax should be easy enough for a designer to modify.  You can then use it as `settings.opacity`.

You could then use [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) to merge settings defined by the designer with your default settings:

```
var defaults = {
    opacity: 0.9,
    speed: 500
}

settings = $.extend({}, defaults, settings);
// returns { opacity: 0.5, speed: 500 }
```

Comment: that makes me think that it will make the designer lazier to create stuff, what do u think?

Comment: I meant that the designers are all CSS, when they have to edit other files they tend to not do it. But I guess I will use your answer, since is the most proper solution

Answer (score 2):

@lonesomdays solution is the obvious one, and a good one at that.
Here is my take;

```
function getConfig(className,property)
{
    var dummy = $('<span class="' + className + '" />');
    var value = dummy.appendTo('body').css(property);
    dummy.remove();
    return value;
}
```

To call it use `getConfig('constants_someid','opacity')`

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5GWHU/

Comment: Obviously not the smart choice, but more in line with the original question than other answers

Answer (score 0):

Defining them as CSS classes is a good method since, as you mentioned, it can be better maintained.

However, I don't think you should be pulling individual properties out of a single CSS `constants` class. Instead define multiple, *meaningful* classes and add/remove them using jQuery.

For example, individual CSS classes for adding dynamically:

```
.faded-out {
   opacity: 0.5;
}

.highlight {
   background: yellow;
}
```

And the relevant jQuery:

```
jQuery('.someElements').addClass('faded-out');
jQuery('.otherElements').removeClass('highlight');
```

Comment: The disadvantage is that this prevents animation unless you use the jQuery UI addClass extension.

Comment: @lonesomeday, very true, though jQuery UI's addClass is a good option for this scenario which I forgot to mention.

Comment: the designer can't change teh speed animation from that